# Commercial counter fridge not cooling after 6 months being off

Tags: refrigerator

I have a counter fridge [Polar G379](https://www.cateringhygiene.co.uk/shop/polar-g379-u-series-four-door-slimline-counter-refrigerator-449-litres.html) which had been working fine. Six months ago I turned it off and only turned it back on recently but the fridge is not cooling.

I've checked the condenser and it does not seem to be dusty.

Any suggestions as to what the problem might be?

Comment: Almost certainly something requiring a real refrigeration technician to resolve - not a DIY friendly problem, even if you are in the UK (as the weblink would suggest) and not subject to the US refrigeration licensing requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I would check the coils to make sure they are clean. It may also take more than a few hours of run time to cool down.
If 8+ hours still no cold can you reach the compressor ? Is it running? The thermostat may not be turning the compressor on.

Last would be a capacitor check they do fail while sitting so the compressor may not be starting and overheating shutting down you would not know, it’s just not running, it may be worth a try unplug for an hour plug back in with thermostat turned down, if not starting bad cap or thermostat both are diy possibly.

If R134A I have seen it for sale those small units only take 4-6 oz. I don’t know how they sell the stuff I have to show my license or be on file to purchase.

I have checked it’s real R134A, so even a minor recharge may be possible. But check the other things first.

Comment: Linked page says it's R600a (isobutane, IIRC - flammable refrigerant.)

Comment: Sorry, the linked page does indeed say R600a but it's R134a for my fridge - it says so on the sticker on the back of my fridge. I think the one linked on the web page is just a newer/different version of G379.

Comment: Many thanks Ed, will check as per your suggestions